# How to lowercase the first alphabet of a key in an object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ecmascript-6

I have a JavaScript object and  I want to make the first letter of the key to lower case.

For example: the key is Title then it should be title; for key PublishDate it should be publishDate and if the key is Publish_Date then it should be publish_Date and so on.

The object can be more complex depending on the data received form the server

```js
[ 
   { 
      "clientId":1,
      "Title":"Test",
      "Message":"fdsf",
      "Image":"",
      "PublishDate":"Feb  5 2020 12:00AM",
      "UserID":null,
      "authorName":"fdsfd",
      "announceType":"Admin",
      "IsAdmin":0,
      "TimeAgo":"1 days"
   },
   { 
      "clientId":1,
      "Title":"Test",
      "Message":"testing",
      "Image":"",
      "PublishDate":"Feb  5 2020 12:00AM",
      "UserID":null,
      "authorName":"Lorem Ipsum",
      "announceType":"Admin",
      "IsAdmin":0,
      "TimeAgo":"1 days"
   },
   { 
      "clientId":1,
      "Title":"Test",
      "Message":"testing ",
      "Image":"",
      "PublishDate":"Feb  5 2020 12:00AM",
      "UserID":null,
      "authorName":"Lorem Ipsum",
      "announceType":"CEO",
      "IsAdmin":0,
      "TimeAgo":"1 days"
   }
]
```

Comment: Cant you just output it that way? Where does the object (there is no JSON object) come from?

Answer (score 2):

You can [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) each object to a new object created using [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries). This method takes an array of `[key, value]` pairs which you can get from using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) on each object within your `.map()` method. For each key in the entries, you can make its first letter lowercase.

See example below:

```js
const data = [ { "clientId":1, "Title":"Test", "Message":"fdsf", "Image":"", "PublishDate":"Feb  5 2020 12:00AM", "UserID":null, "authorName":"fdsfd", "announceType":"Admin", "IsAdmin":0, "TimeAgo":"1 days" }, { "clientId":1, "Title":"Test", "Message":"testing", "Image":"", "PublishDate":"Feb  5 2020 12:00AM", "UserID":null, "authorName":"Lorem Ipsum", "announceType":"Admin", "IsAdmin":0, "TimeAgo":"1 days" }, { "clientId":1, "Title":"Test", "Message":"testing ", "Image":"", "PublishDate":"Feb  5 2020 12:00AM", "UserID":null, "authorName":"Lorem Ipsum", "announceType":"CEO", "IsAdmin":0, "TimeAgo":"1 days" } ];

const lowerCase = str => str[0].toLowerCase() + str. slice(1);
const res = data.map(
  obj => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(
    ([k, v]) => [lowerCase(k), v])
  )
);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important;} /* ignore */
```

Currently, `Object.fromEntries()` does have [limited browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries#Browser_compatibility), however, it can be easily polyfilled. An alternative to it could be to use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and map each entry to an object, which you spread to then assign to a larger object:

```js
const data = [ { "clientId":1, "Title":"Test", "Message":"fdsf", "Image":"", "PublishDate":"Feb  5 2020 12:00AM", "UserID":null, "authorName":"fdsfd", "announceType":"Admin", "IsAdmin":0, "TimeAgo":"1 days" }, { "clientId":1, "Title":"Test", "Message":"testing", "Image":"", "PublishDate":"Feb  5 2020 12:00AM", "UserID":null, "authorName":"Lorem Ipsum", "announceType":"Admin", "IsAdmin":0, "TimeAgo":"1 days" }, { "clientId":1, "Title":"Test", "Message":"testing ", "Image":"", "PublishDate":"Feb  5 2020 12:00AM", "UserID":null, "authorName":"Lorem Ipsum", "announceType":"CEO", "IsAdmin":0, "TimeAgo":"1 days" } ];

const lowerCase = str => str[0].toLowerCase() + str. slice(1);
const res = data.map(
  obj => Object.assign({}, ...Object.entries(obj).map(
    ([k, v]) => ({[lowerCase(k)]: v})
  ))
);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important;} /* ignore */
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (let key in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    const newKey = key[0].toLowerCase() + key.substr(1);
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(newKey)) {
      obj[newKey] = obj[key];
      delete obj[key];
    }    
  }
}
```

Edit:

I'm not questioning what you want to achieve by doing this.

Also, it's worth noting that this will put the new property to the "end" of the object.

Edit 2:

Removed the `break;` from my original answer, as I thought you just wanted the first property to be amended. This version will amded all properties.

Comment: Your method would in theory overwrite already matching values `{Test: '123', test: 'abc'}`. Before adding a new key you should check if it already exists. Also your method removes alreay correct keys with the `delete` in the end if `newKey` and `key` are identical.

Comment: That is true, but who's to say which one wins in the absence of any requirements

Comment: the requirement was due to my project already integerated with the lowecase varialbe and not the serivce has change to object case, so i cannot remap the entire object again.

Comment: @Kurt Hamilton: You remove all keyvaluepairs which already start with lowercase.

Comment: @Lain And then re-add them. This method preserves the original order of the properties, it just ensures that they all start with a lower case character

Comment: No, it does not. Test it with `{Meow: 123, cucu: 456}`. You will end up with one property left. Your `delete` will remove keys with already correct patterns, since old and new names are equal.

Comment: @Lain. Oops, yes, I see what you mean now.

Answer (score 1):

Taking your question literally, this code will lowerCase the first alphabetic char, regardless where it starts

```js
const data = [ { "clientId":1, "0 Title":"Test", "   000Message":"fdsf", "Image":"", "PublishDate":"Feb  5 2020 12:00AM", "UserID":null, "authorName":"fdsfd", "announceType":"Admin", "IsAdmin":0, "00000  TimeAgo":"1 days" }, { "clientId":1, "Title":"Test", "Message":"testing", "Image":"", "PublishDate":"Feb  5 2020 12:00AM", "UserID":null, "authorName":"Lorem Ipsum", "announceType":"Admin", "IsAdmin":0, "TimeAgo":"1 days" }, { "clientId":1, "Title":"Test", "Message":"testing ", "Image":"", "PublishDate":"Feb  5 2020 12:00AM", "UserID":null, "authorName":"Lorem Ipsum", "announceType":"CEO", "IsAdmin":0, "TimeAgo":"1 days" } ];

const re = /([^A-Z]+)?([A-Z]{1})(.*)/
const dat = obj => {
  let newobj = {}
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => newobj[key.replace(re,function(_,a,b,c,d) { return (a!=undefined?a:"")+b.toLowerCase() + c })] = obj[key]);
  return newobj;
};

console.log(data.map(entry => dat(entry)))
```

Comment: By interpreting the question precisely, this solution would be wrong. For instance by using {" Title": "Wayne"}. Whitespaces a not alphabetical characters.

Comment: Why would anyone have a space in the beginning of a key? If they did , we need a regex

Comment: Well thanks, but that was not really meant seriously. Nice solution nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```js
const data = [ { "clientId":1, "Title":"Test", "Message":"fdsf", "Image":"", "PublishDate":"Feb  5 2020 12:00AM", "UserID":null, "authorName":"fdsfd", "announceType":"Admin", "IsAdmin":0, "TimeAgo":"1 days" }, { "clientId":1, "Title":"Test", "Message":"testing", "Image":"", "PublishDate":"Feb  5 2020 12:00AM", "UserID":null, "authorName":"Lorem Ipsum", "announceType":"Admin", "IsAdmin":0, "TimeAgo":"1 days" }, { "clientId":1, "Title":"Test", "Message":"testing ", "Image":"", "PublishDate":"Feb  5 2020 12:00AM", "UserID":null, "authorName":"Lorem Ipsum", "announceType":"CEO", "IsAdmin":0, "TimeAgo":"1 days" } ];

let test = data.map(t => dat(t))
function dat(obj) {
  var key, keys = Object.keys(obj);
  var n = keys.length;
  var newobj = {}
  while (n--) {
    key = keys[n];
    newobj[key.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + key.slice(1)] = obj[key];
  }
  return newobj
}

console.log(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:
Added Alternate method using `forEach`.

Using `reduce`, `Object.keys`, `toLowerCase` and template strings

```js
const process = data =>
  data.map(item =>
    Object.keys(item).reduce(
      (acc, key) => (
        (acc[`${key[0].toLowerCase()}${key.slice(1)}`] = item[key]), acc
      ),
      {}
    )
  );
  
const processAlt = data =>
  data.map(
    item => (
      (obj = {}),
      Object.keys(item).forEach(
        key => (obj[`${key[0].toLowerCase()}${key.slice(1)}`] = item[key])
      ),
      obj
    )
  );
  
const data = [
  {
    clientId: 1,
    Title: "Test",
    Message: "fdsf",
    Image: "",
    PublishDate: "Feb  5 2020 12:00AM",
    UserID: null,
    authorName: "fdsfd",
    announceType: "Admin",
    IsAdmin: 0,
    TimeAgo: "1 days"
  },
  {
    clientId: 1,
    Title: "Test",
    Message: "testing",
    Image: "",
    PublishDate: "Feb  5 2020 12:00AM",
    UserID: null,
    authorName: "Lorem Ipsum",
    announceType: "Admin",
    IsAdmin: 0,
    TimeAgo: "1 days"
  },
  {
    clientId: 1,
    Title: "Test",
    Message: "testing ",
    Image: "",
    PublishDate: "Feb  5 2020 12:00AM",
    UserID: null,
    authorName: "Lorem Ipsum",
    announceType: "CEO",
    IsAdmin: 0,
    TimeAgo: "1 days"
  }
];

console.log(process(data));
console.log(processAlt(data));
```

Comment: Is the reduce really needed? Could we not use a forEach instead?

Comment: @mplungjan, oh right, reduce not really helpful here.

Comment: You really do not want to spend a line creating an object to copy to!? ;) See my answer for a simpler solution

Answer (score 0):

Using some destructuring

```js
const lowerCaseKeys = obj => Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).map(([[firstLetter, ...rest], value]) => 
      [firstLetter.toLowerCase() + rest.join(''), value])
);
```